# To hide or to remove html loader?

Tags: javascript, html, animated-gif

We discussed this topic with colleagues... Is it better to hide/show or add/remove GIF loader in HTML using JavaScript? We came to this:

Hide/show pros:

- showing the loader does not require its creation using JavaScript so it should be faster; Is negligible?
- is simpler
- GIF picture is readily available

Add/remove pros:

- removing the loader (thus DOM element) should speed up querying/working with DOM elements
- if your site has a lot of loaders, it is possibly slower to download; Can negate using HTML5 Application Cache?
- lazy loading - GIF picture needs to be downloaded only if it is necessary

Are there more pros/cons? How do you work with GIF loaders? Which technique do you recommend? Lets assume two scenarios:
There are multiple loaders on the page...
a.) using a single GIF picture
b.) using more GIF pictures

Comment: If a certain task requires a loading animation to be displayed then  you don't need to be concerned about the time required to show and hide or add and remove a dom element. My suggestion ist alway to keep your DOM clean.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, hide and show is a better approach because it doesn't mess with the DOM. There probably isn't any performance benefits but if you remove it from the DOM and then re-add it later it is possible to lose JS event bindings unless using jQuery's .on() event handler.

May I also add that while GIFs are a long supported feature of most browsers, CSS animations can create much smoother loading indicators and have smaller file sizes, too.

Comment: `.on` is used for both direct and delegate events. The event handler is always attached to the object where `.on` is called for. If the delegate selector is attached the callback will be called if a bubbling event is cached for an element that matches that selector. So `.on` does not protect you from _loosing_ the event bindings unless you attach it to the `document`.

Comment: Okay - good to know that. It's been a while since I used jQuery but i remember it fixing an issue I had with hover events on elements loaded in with AJAX so that was my basis.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is, there is no easy answer to your solution. Is it a simple web app? is it a HUGE application that needs to have an animated gif attached to it to load?

If you have a larger application:

simply preload the animated gif (either using modenizr.js or css) and then you can simply make it the background of a div that you can append to anything at any time and remove it gracefully. (extremely fast, saves memory).  the downside is that if you are not very experienced chances are you might forget to remove it correctly.

in your css

`.loading{height:100px;width:100px;background-image:url(loader.gif);background-position:center center;}`

this is now your "loading div" and css will load the background image into memory.

next

what ever ajax div you have (lets assume it is #content)

`$("#content").append("<div class='loading'></div");`

then whenever you want to get rid of it ( probably on the ajax return call)

`$('.loading').remove();`

Comment: If you suggest to preload the `gif` with `css` you should probably show how. Because just creating a rule like `.loading { background-image: url(loading.gif); }` would not load the image until there is an element on the site where the rule is applied to. And why does this depend on how large the application is?

Comment: If there was not element with the class `loading` in the DOM before `$("#content").append("<div class='loading'></div>");`  is called, then the image will be loaded at the time `$("#content").append("<div class='loading'></div>");` is called but not before. The existence of a `background-image:url(loader.gif);` does not automatically load the image it only loads it at the time where the rule is applied the first time.

Comment: @t.niese for instance. I have a web app with 20/30 sliding views and each of them load content. A. I dont want that many static divs lying around and b you have to be precise with your naming conventions. However if there is one div that loads content in and out by all means just show and hide...

Comment: @t.niese yes but css loads it much faster than trying to dynamically loading an image....

Comment: Faster, most likely (but I did not test). Much faster, well i don't think you notice a difference. But css alone without a corresponding element in DOM would not load an image. So no preloading. Thats e.g. why you see flickering for hovers without using sprites (`a { background-image: url(image.jpg); }`, `a:hover {background-image: url(image_hover.jpg) }`) because `image_hover.jpg` will start to download when the mouse is over and therefore you have a short time where the image is not present.

Comment: thats why we use sprites =)    to resolve that `var im = new image(); im.src = "yourgif.gif"` ... that will load it into memory just fine

Answer (score -1):

I think this piece of coding resolve the problem:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
     $("#loader").remove(); //call the image with id like #loader
 });
```